# Docker container stops after create command

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile, sh

I am trying to create a shell script that builds an image and then runs the container and executes commands that I pass to it, such as npm install, etc.

At the moment, I have

```
#!/bin/bash

docker container create -it --name testt <image_name>
docker container start testt
winpty docker container exec -it testt bash


read -rsp $'Press any key to continue...\n' -n1 key
```

And the first create command executes, but when I try to start it, it says the container is not running.

edit to add Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.16.2-alpine 

RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash

WORKDIR /home/build

COPY . .
```

Comment: Do you need it running if you are just going to jump into a bash shell? If you do need it running, then what is your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile? Is it something that will keep your container alive? Perhaps it would help if you explained what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I do not need to have it running necessarily, but I do need to run several commands in a sequence, installing a file, removing a certain folder from it, and tar.gz zipping that up and SFTPing it.

I do not have a CMD or entrypoint at the moment, from my understanding I could run these commands to create the container and run commands to it.

Comment: If you put the word `RUN` before each of the commands you want to run, you've described a Dockerfile, which is the standard way to build up an image with software preinstalled.  Using `docker exec` to install software in a container isn't a best practice: containers get deleted extremely routinely and all of your work will get lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your image you need to use docker run and not docker start

```
docker run -d -it <image name>
```

The -d will keep it running in the background once you exit the container

**Edit**
From the terminal try building the image with the following code snippet

```
docker build -t <imageName>:<tag>
```

Then try running the image with

```
docker run -d -it <imageName>:<tag>
```

Next run

```
docker ps -a
```

Check if the container is still running

If it is still running enter the container like so

```
docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, but the result is the same, "the container is not running." So I'm unsure of what is happening.

Comment: ```FROM node:8.16.2-alpine 

    RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash

    WORKDIR /home/build

    COPY . .```

Sorry, not sure how to format in the comment correctly.

Comment: Have you tried running the image not from the bash script with the suggestion I have above?

Comment: yes and it runs it, but it immediately exits the container and is no longer running.

Comment: Can you do a docker ps -a  and grab the container ID and then run a docker logs <container ID> Make sure that the container is getting up and running correctly

Comment: /bin/sh: build.sh: not found is the result

is this because I don't have an entrypoint for the container?

Comment: I couldn't see the entire Dockerfile in the comment. If you edit your original post you should be able to add it there and then I can address the problem

Comment: The entire Dockerfile has been edited into the original post.